# what are the difference between document and dbObject when using MongoDB and Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, dbobject

1. what are the difference between document and dbObject when using MongoDB and Java?
2. when will we use each of them?

Comment: WHAT??? Seems You ask about some variables ...

Comment: This will help http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/bson/documents/

Answer (score 1):

- [Document](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/Document.html): Is a class
- [DBObject](https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.13/com/mongodb/DBObject.html): Is an interface

The DBObject interface adds some specific behavior to BSONObject for MongoDB documents.